# How to install linux mint 17.1 to encrypted raid 0 array

Tags: installation, raid, linux-mint, raid-0

I just got a new SSD and I wanted to install Linux Mint 17.1 to a raid 0 array of SSDs. I also want the array to be encrypted. I tried the following [guide](http://www.tecmint.com/create-raid0-in-linux/) and got mdadm to setup a software array and the instructed the Linux Mint installer to use the disk `/dev/md0` as the install target, but grub failed to install and when I rebooted, grub said "no such disk or device".

Is this possible? I am not sure what to do. I have 2 regular HDDs I am using to store extra data as well. I don't know if these can be used somehow to hold grub as they are unencrypted and not in a raid array.

Comment: The Mint & Ubuntu installers can set up encryption themselves, it should be a lot easier than going it manually. But I don't know if they'll support a raid array.

Answer (score 1):

you MUST to create a small partition out of the raid0 for /boot.Grub will be instaled there and define the root partition as MD

Answer (score 0):

Grub2 can boot from a Raid0, it is a matter of adding the parameter when doing install-grub2, it also supports multiply levels of LUKS (again on such parameter add the string for luks).

I had tested it on a virtual machine... my grub.cfg file is inside:

Ext4 over a LUKS over a Raid 0 of 3 HDDs, each one over its own LUKS.

At boot i must enter LUKS key for each disk, then LUKS key for Raid 0.

I also use different algorithms, etc on each LUKS.

It was just a 'concept' test, but it worked. It also works with grub.cfg inside a LVM, and also having a long mixed chain of LVM, Raid, LUKS...

Grub2 was manually installed (only using grub2-install) and grub.cfg was manually created... i hate all that Grub2 stuff that let a script to create grub.cfg, specially 'grub2-mkconfig' (i avoid using it), i preffer to write my own grub.cfg file by my own.

Yes, i tend to use to bootloaders in chain... main one, the one i create grub.cfg manually, then i choose what to boot, Windows X, Y, Z ... Linux A, B, C, etc... and let each Linux manage its own bootloader as it wants but not letting any OS touch the main bootloader... isolating each OS.

For such i did a lot of tests on a virtual machine, some as proof of concept, some for benchmark, some to take knownledge, etc., prior to do it on my hardware.

My main URL as a base point to start, was reading this:

http://www.pavelkogan.com/2014/05/23/luks-full-disk-encryption/

It explains how to install Grub2 under LVM under LUKS, etc. and have /boot inside LVM+LUKS, etc.